# Android: setting imageResource randomly from 6 images

Tags: android, image, random

I saw an example from a book that for setting ImageResource using the code:

```
spot.setImageResource(random.nextInt(2) == 0 ? R.drawable.star200_blue : R.drawable.star200_green);
```

This can set the Spot randomly out of these 2 images, either blue or green.

### Question:

Actually I found little information from the book about the usage of `:`.

I now have 6 images (red, orange, yellow, green, blue, purple), how could the above codes be modified such that the spot can be set randomly from these 6 images randomly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add all image IDs in an `int[]` array and then use

`spot.setImageResource(imagesArray[new Random().nextInt(6)]);`

where `imagesArray` is your array containing image IDs

Comment: so : is solely used when there are 2 choices only?

Comment: Yes it is used when you have a `true/false` condition. If your condition(`random.nextInt(2) == 0` in this case) is `true` then the statement after `?` will be executed or else if it is `false` the statement after `:` will be excuted